# Rails installation Error - could not find gem jquery-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install rails on my office's system.
I have installed rails using link http://railsinstaller.org/
Then I created new proj using command![enter image description here][1] 'rails new temp' 
It throws error:

```
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
could not reach rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/
could not find gem 'jquery-rails <>= 0> x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your gemfile.
```

Is it anything to do with proxy firewall, or am i missing any steps?

Pls reply soon. Thanks

Comment: What is in your Gemfile?

Comment: using rails on windows, as you seem to try, is renown to be a real pain in the @$$. if possible, stop that madness right now, use any *nix distro of your choice and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your apps directory and fine Gemfile.

In your Gemfile check if you have `gem 'jquery-rails'`

If not type that into the editor and save it and then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

If the gem 'jquery-rails' is mentioned in your gem file and then you are installing the gems via bundle install and getting this error , Then it is a proxy firewall that will block you from reaching repository. 
Same experience i faced via Windows Command prompt.